# Codeigniter Get Nested Hierarchical Data from Database

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-2

How can i get Hierarchical Data from db in Codeigniter. I read this : 
http://www.sitepoint.com/hierarchical-data-database/
And i do good that but i cant optimize this tutorial with my model, controler and views

```
 Default Category
   |----- Sub category
          | ----One more category
               |----- Somthing else
```

I try but dont show sub category:

My model:

```
   public function fetchChildren($parent, $level) {    
       $this->handler = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM content_categories WHERE parent_id='".$parent."' ");
          foreach($this->handler->result() as  $row ) {
              $this->data[$row->id] = $row;
              //echo str_repeat('  ',$level).$row['title']."\n"; 
          }

          return $this->data;
```

}

Controller :

```
  $this->data['node'] = $this->categories_model->fetchChildren(' ',0);
```

Views:

```
<table class="module_table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
             <th><?php echo lang('categories_table_title'); ?></th>     
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
        <?php foreach ($node as $row) : ?>
        <tr>
            <th> <?php echo str_repeat('|----', 0+1). $row->title ?> </th>
        </tr>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </tbody>

</table>
```

And output is :

```
----Default
----Default
----Test Category 1
----Seccond Test Category 1
----Another Test Category 1
```

When i do this in model all work fine but when i try that to call in controler and loop in view i have result like above example:

This work onlu in model:

```
   public function fetchChildren($parent, $level) {    
       $this->handler = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM content_categories WHERE parent_id='".$parent."' ");
          foreach($this->handler->result() as  $row ) {
             echo str_repeat('|-----',$level).$row->title."\n"; 
            $this->fetchChildren($row->title, $level+1);
          }

          return $this->data;
```

}

And like output i have :

```
Default
    |----Test Category 1
    |----Seccond Test Category 1
        |----Another Test Category 1
```

Any one have solution or example thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try storing the level value for each category.

In your model:

```
public function fetchChildren($parent, $level){
    $this->handler = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM content_categories WHERE parent_id='".$parent."' ");
    foreach($this->handler->result() as  $row ) {
        $row->level = $level;
        $this->data[] = $row; 
        $this->fetchChildren($row->title, $level+1);
    }
    return $this->data;
}
```

In your controller:

```
$this->data['node'] = $this->categories_model->fetchChildren(' ',0);
```

In your view

```
<table class="module_table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
             <th><?php echo lang('categories_table_title'); ?></th>     
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php foreach ($node as $row) : ?>
        <tr>
            <th><?php echo str_repeat('|----', $row->level). $row->title ?> </th>
        </tr>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: ***$row->level*** is function argument no Db obj. what value can i put in views to replace ***$row->level*** i str_repeat

Comment: And with this i again have some output like in above

Comment: @Jony did you update your model function? I'm setting the level property for each result in the database so in you can get that value in your view